# Calculating the right angled triangle's cathetus

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

We just started learning the Pythagorean theorem at school and we got a pretty difficult assignment.

> 5 meter tall bamboo broke and the top of it touched the floor 2 meters
>   from the base of the bamboo. What height did it break at?

I've tried all sorts of different approaches, but I just can't get it right. I'm starting to think it's unsolvable.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've tried using the Pythagorean theorem (blue is the bamboo after it broke, gray is where the bamboo was before it broke):

[image]

Comment: Questions are generally expected to be accompanied with evidence of effort, so it would be nice if you could share what you thought was the most promising of your approaches. Have you tried drawing the situation?

Comment: @epimorphic I've just updated the question. I hope it's enough. Didn't really do much because as I said we've just started learning the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated (I won't write the units of meters):

$$c+b=5, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ c^2=a^2+b^2.$$

You want to know either $c$ or $b$, so, you can write the first equation as $c=5-b$ or $b=5-c$. Now you can plug one of these into the second equation, and you would get an equation in terms of $a$ and $c$ or $b$, i.e. you CAN now solve for $b$ or $c$ and get the desired answer.

Comment: Could you please supply me with an example because I'm a little confused.

Comment: @TadejGašparovič for example, the first equation tells you that $c=5-b$, right? then you can square it: $c^2=(5-b)^2$. Now, you also have the equation $c^2=a^2+b^2$. But you know what $c^2$ is. It's $(5-b)^2$!, therefore you plug this value in the second equation:  $(5-b)^2=a^2+b^2$. You know that $a^2=4$, now you can solve for $b$. Do it, and I recommend you to take the other case in which $b^2=(5-c)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

As you already observed,
$$b+c=5, \tag{1}$$
$$c^2 = 4 + b^2.$$
From the second equation we can find that
$$c^2 - b^2 = 4.$$
Factor the left-hand side:
$$(c + b)(c - b) = 4.$$
This looks useful, since we already know that $c+b = b+c = 5.$
That is, we now know that $$5(c - b) = 4. \tag{2}$$

Now we have a system of two simultaneous linear equations in $b$ and $c$,
namely the equations labeled $(1)$ and $(2)$.
We can solve for $b$ and $c$ in whatever way we would usually solve
such a system of equations;
or in this case, we might notice that if we set
$a = \frac{b+c}{2}$ and $d = \frac{c-b}{2}$,
then $c = a + d$ and $b = a - d$.
(This last bit is handy to have in your bag of tricks
when you happen to know the sum and difference of two unknown values.)